# Finding k items in a binary tree

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability

Let us be given a binary tree of height $n$ (and $2^n$ leaves) among which we search $k$ items, where  $k < < 2^n$. Suppose we have a test that shows if in the children and childrens-children generations of a node at least one item is hidden (sorry for my prose speak). The question is: how many tests do we need in average (or expectation under uniform law) to find all $k$ items? In computer science speak it would be the expected run-time of the following algorithm. Of course, finding one item needs $n$ tests (and so $k \times n$  is a trivial upper bound to find $k$ items). Now, running through the tree we cut out useless subtrees on each "hunt" for one item, we expect less and less tests for the following ones to be needed, and so I expect much less than $k \times n$ tests needed in average.

I guess this question is well-known, but I lack keywords in combinatorics / computer science to find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can associate leaf elements of the binary tree with binary codes of length $n$. The code we assign to a leaf is the sequence of left and right traversals that you must make to reach the element in the binary tree. Assign a 0 for each left traversal and a 1 for each right traversal. For instance, if you must traverse the tree by going to a left child, then another left child, then a right child, the code for this node in the tree would be "001".

Let $x_1, \ldots, x_k$ be the binary codes associated with the $k$ elements that you are searching for in the binary tree. (note that these binary representations will have length $n$, the depth of the tree).

**In the worst case it takes time $\Omega(k + k(n-\log k))$ to find all $k$ elements that you are searching for**
In particular, for $k \ll 2^n$ this is $\Omega(k\cdot n)$.

**proof:**
We construct worst case elements as follows:
We chose the elements such that the first $\log k$ digits of the code of $x_i$ is the binary representation of $i$. 
Note that the prefix consisting of the first $k$ digits of the binary codes for each $x_i$ differ, so the $x_i$ are ancestors in the tree of distinct nodes at depth $\log k$. Traversing this tree of depth $\log k$ to get to these "parent nodes" takes time $\Omega(k)$. From there, we must traverse each subtree starting at the parent node for each of the $k$ items. This takes time $\Omega(k(n - \log k)$ as we must traverse $n-\log k$ more levels / digits in the binary representations.

**In answer to your other question about average running time, I believe that the answer is also $\Omega(n\cdot k)$ average running time.**

The probability that two randomly chosen leaves in your tree share a prefix of length $\ell$ is $1/2^\ell$. 
Thus the expectation of the number of items that share a prefix of length $\ell$ is approximately (it is approximate because you can't actually chose the same element twice) 
${k \choose 2} \cdot 2^{-\ell}$.

Setting $\ell = 2\log k$ we get that the expected number of elements that share a prefix of length $2\log k$ is less than $1$.

Hence you should still expect to need to spend time $\Omega(k\cdot n)$ on the problem.